# Set values in NumPy chaining two slicings

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Is there a way in Numpy array to update the values of an array using two indices (to be chained)?

This is a simple example:

```
import numpy as np

if __name__ == '__main__':
    x = np.array([0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0])
    print('1: ', x) #1:  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
    indx = np.array([0,2,4,6,8])
    x[indx] += 1
    print('2: ', x) #[1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0]

    indx2 = np.array([0, 2, 4])
    x[indx][indx2] += 1
    print('3: ', x) #[1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0]
```

In the beginning, I updated x using the **indx** array and it works, but then when I created another "sub index" array which is **indx2** and tried to update x, nothing changed!

Comment: `x[indx]` is one operation, producing a new array (a copy, not a view).  `[indx2]=` operates on this new array, not `x`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not chain indexing, it might create a view instead of indexing. Instead, you should do:

```
x[indx[indx2]] += 1
```

**Explanation**: `indx[indx2]` returns an `np.array` with values `[0,4,8]`, and then `x[...]` is just normal indexing, and you can update the values as wanted. This does not depend on whether `indx[indx2]` is a view or actual indexing.

Comment: Thanks! this is what I want.